# Using group by and having in a JPA query

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jpql

How would you do the following using the JPA query language?

```
select * from person where email in
(select email from person group by email having count(email)>1)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found a solution:

```
select p from Person p
where p.email in (
    select q.email
    from Person q
    group by q.email having count(q.email)>1)
order by p.email, p.id
```

Answer (score 3):

From [this link](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/structure), there's a explanation of the general structure of a JPA SELECT Query:

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
[WHERE ...]
[GROUP BY ... [HAVING ...]]
[ORDER BY ...]
```