# "could not extract ResultSet" in JPQL GROUP BY query

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

In my Spring Boot 1.5 application with Spring Data JPA, I have a `TDR` table like:

```
     Table TDR
-----------------------
id | c_id | m_id | p_id
 1 |   1  |    1 |    1
 2 |   1  |    1 |    2
 3 |   2  |    1 |    1
 4 |   2  |    1 |    2
 5 |   3  |    1 |    1
```

where I need to find the last records grouped by `m_id` and `p_id`. With PostgreSQL SQL, I do this with the `MAX` aggregate function:

```
SELECT t.id, t.c_id, t.m_id, t.p_id
FROM (
  SELECT MAX(id) AS id, m_id, p_id 
  FROM tdr
  WHERE m_id = 1                      -- <<< parameterized below
  GROUP BY m_id, p_id
  ) m JOIN tdr t ON t.id = m.id
```

which returns the correct records:

```
     Table TDR
-----------------------
id | c_id | m_id | p_id
 4 |   2  |    1 |    2
 5 |   3  |    1 |    1
```

Since the `GROUP BY` does not include `c_id`, the SQL is structured as [correlated sub-query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) and matched with a join (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601948/must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function) for details).

I'd like to convert this SQL to JPQL with this [Lombok `@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html) entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "TDR")
public class TDR implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name="m_id")
    private M m;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name="p_id")
    private P p;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name="c_id")
    private C c;
}
```

but my JPQL for the correlated sub-query with parameterized m ID (`:m_id`):

```
SELECT t FROM TDR t WHERE t.id in (
  SELECT MAX(t.id) AS id, t.m, t.p FROM TDR t WHERE t.m = :m GROUP BY t.m, t.p
  )
```

results in this error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
   // at ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
   // at ...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: subquery has too many columns
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you posted the actual error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select just the join column in the correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT t FROM TDR t WHERE t.id in (
  SELECT MAX(t.id) FROM TDR t WHERE t.m = :m GROUP BY t.m, t.p
  )
```

The [ObjectDB GROUP BY article](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/group) was helpful as was this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439910/using-group-by-and-having-in-a-jpa-query).

Answer (score 0):

The thing that jumps out to me is that your first SELECT:

`SELECT FROM`

...doesn't state which columns you're selecting